# How to bind first object data to modify screen?

Tags: angular, windows, typescript, angular4-forms, angular4-router

Show to display the first object of an array from API response in angular 4. If I get % response from API then I want to display first object data to my next modify screen. How can I do this?

Comment: Then you can get the first element of the array like `array[0]`.

Comment: Please include some code of what you have tried so far.